# How to get mime type from a bitmap object in android?

Tags: android, bitmap, mime-types

I want to get mime type of a bitmap object.
Actually I have compressed a bitmap using

```
bitmap.compress (Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG , 100, stream);
```

Now I want to cross check the format, outBounds and memory space size. But I don't wanna do a lengthy or a tedious task eg. to convert it to back to stream and then convert it again to BItmap using BitmapFactory with options.

Comment: Maybe you are talking about [outMimeType()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#outMimeType) method?

Answer (score 3):

Like Dmitry suggests, if what you have is a compressed image in a stream, then you *do* need to decode it using a BitmapFactory to tell what type it is.  (Technically, you *could* also read the stream yourself and run your own *ad hoc* file format checks on it, but I assume you'd prefer to use existing tools rather than rolling your own.)

One optimization you can and should make is to set [BitmapFactory.Options.inJustDecodeBounds](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inJustDecodeBounds) to avoid needlessly decoding the entire image if you just want to know what type it is.  After decoding, the [outMimeType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#outMimeType) property should give you the type of the image.

As for the literal question in your title, it doesn't make sense.  A [Bitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html) has no MIME type — it's just a container for an array of pixels.  You can compress the bitmap into a stream using various formats, like JPEG, PNG or WEBP, but that just gives you a compressed copy of the image.